# pip install misses some generated files when writing installed-files.txt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

When `pip install`ing a project that has a custom `build_py` command which generates an additional file in the build directory, the installed-files.txt file generated by pip on an install does not list the generated file. As a result, when I uninstall the distribution, it leaves behind my generated file.

I imagine that I'm failing to register the generated file somehow, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

What must I change so that pip's installed-files.txt lists my generated file?

### Reproduction steps

Create the following file system entries.

```
installed-files-missing-project
├── install-entry-missing
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

Put the following content in setup.py.

```
import os

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py


def touch(fname, times=None):
    with open(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, times)


class my_build_py(build_py):
    def run(self):
        if not self.dry_run:
            target_dir = os.path.join(self.build_lib, "install-entry-missing")
            self.mkpath(target_dir)
            touch(os.path.join(target_dir, "my_file.txt"))
            # TODO: missing registration of "my_file.txt"?
        build_py.run(self)


setup_args = dict(
    name='install-entry-missing',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='',
    author='author',
    author_email='author@example.com',
    packages = ["install-entry-missing"],
    cmdclass={'build_py': my_build_py}
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(**setup_args)
```

From the `install-entry-missing-project` directory, run `pip install .`.

The installed directory will contain both my_file.txt and __init__.py. However, examining the egg-info directory's installed-files.txt will show that my_file.txt is not listed. As a result, `pip uninstall install-entry-missing` will remove __init__.py but not my_file.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaner code than that suggested in [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25857532/1220555) can be had by overriding the `get_outputs` method of `build_py` instead of using `install_egg_info`:

```
import os

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py


def touch(fname, times=None):
    with open(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, times)


class my_build_py(build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.my_outputs = []
        if not self.dry_run:
            target_dir = os.path.join(self.build_lib, "install-entry-missing")
            self.mkpath(target_dir)
            output = os.path.join(target_dir, "my_file.txt")
            touch(output)
            self.my_outputs.append(output)
        build_py.run(self)

    def get_outputs(self):
        outputs = build_py.get_outputs(self)
        outputs.extend(self.my_outputs)
        return outputs


setup_args = dict(
    name='install-entry-missing',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='',
    author='author',
    author_email='author@example.com',
    packages = ["install-entry-missing"],
    cmdclass={'build_py': my_build_py}
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(**setup_args)
```

While the method used in [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25857532/1220555) works, overriding `install_egg_info` in order to update the *installed-files.txt* is semantically dubious since you are updating a list of files relating to what is installed in the *egg-info* directory. Overriding `get_outputs` in `build_py` keeps the list of changed files closer to where they are generated and makes it much easier to deal with a situation where the files generated are only determined at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to override the `install_egg_info` command and append an entry to its `self.outputs` list. Each entry in the `self.outputs` list will generate an entry in the final installed-files.txt.

Modifying the code above, a correct solution is:

```
import os

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py
from setuptools.command.install_egg_info import install_egg_info


def touch(fname, times=None):
    with open(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, times)


class my_build_py(build_py):
    def run(self):
        if not self.dry_run:
            target_dir = os.path.join(self.build_lib, "install-entry-missing")
            self.mkpath(target_dir)
            touch(os.path.join(target_dir, "my_file.txt"))
            # this file will be registered in my_install_egg_info
        build_py.run(self)


class my_install_egg_info(install_egg_info):
    def run(self):
        install_egg_info.run(self)
        target_path = os.path.join(self.install_dir, "my_file.txt")
        self.outputs.append(target_path)


setup_args = dict(
    name='install-entry-missing',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='',
    author='author',
    author_email='author@example.com',
    packages = ["install-entry-missing"],
    cmdclass={'build_py': my_build_py,
              'install_egg_info': my_install_egg_info}
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(**setup_args)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar problem to the one described by this post. The above solutions weren't working. I create a symlink as a post install step of my setup.py.

I followed the code in the pip source code to where it reads the `installed-files.txt` to see what was happening. It turns out that as my file was a symbolic link it was being ignored. On line 50 of pip/req/req_uninstall.py the call to `normalise_path` follows the symlink and simply adds the linked file to the list of paths to be removed. The link itself is not added to the list of files to be removed and so is discarded and left by the installation.

As a work around I changed my symlink to a hard link and pip now completely uninstalls my package.